# hook_form_alter multiple Content Type

Tags: 7, hooks, forms

How I use hook_form_alter with multiple Content Type..

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'register_node_form' || 'session_node_form'){

  if(empty($form['field_event_ref']['und'][0]['nid']['#default_value']))
     {
    $form['field_event_ref']['und'][0]['nid']['#default_value'] = arg(3);
     }
    $form['field_event_ref']['und'][0]['nid']['#disabled'] = True;
     }
  }
```

I want Here to Get Both Of (Register) and (Session) Content type to be alter..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is incorrect, it should be:

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'register_node_form' || $form_id == 'session_node_form') {
    // code here that alters forms for both content types
  }
}
```

The if statement is missing the second `$form_id`.

Also, I wouldn't name the module `custom`. If you are doing that as a demonstration purpose, a typical convention is to use `mymodule_` in posts.

A more readable way:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $content_type_forms = array('register_node_form', 'session_node_form');

  if (in_array($form_id, $content_type_forms)) {
    // code here that alters forms for certain content types
  }
}
```

Comment: It's Work Great, thanks for your comment.. it help me and improve my skill :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7.x)

```
function custom_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Run with all form  content type
}
```